# How to clear character is find first of string in SQL Server column?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in SQL Server, I have this value in table column:

```
98123456789
54782012
```

I want to write a query to find first string if '98' is true then delete that from first string, for example up value this:

```
98123456789   ----> starts with 98 start then clear that  result ====> 123456789
54782012      ----> does not start with 98 then not clear that result ===> 54782012
```

How can I write a query for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE [Table] SET Column=
CASE LEFT(Column, 2) 
 WHEN '98' THEN RIGHT(Column,3)
 ELSE Column
END
```

If your column is of integer type, replace `RIGHT...` with `CAST(RIGHT(Column,3) as int)`

Comment: that's good,thanks for help,but i want update column value,your query is select

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 UPDATE TAB SET COL1= CASE  WHEN COL1 LIKE '98%' THEN SUBSTRING(COL1, 3,LEN(COL1)) 
 ELSE COL1 END FROM TAB
```